# How can I learn to set up a build process?

Tags: python, ci-server

What I was taught at school is all about programming languages, software design, but hardly anything about how to automatically build a software, probably with something like unit testing integrated.

Please tell me how do one start learning to set up a build process for his project.

If this is too abstract to make any sense, I would add that I use **Python** and do web programming with **Django**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language? What platform?

Comment: Better to migrate to programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the process you are referring to is called [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).

One of the popular tools for that is Hudson (see [Hudson with django](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2010/03/08/django-and-hudson-ci-day-1/)). Make sure to also check out the [django-continuous-integration](http://github.com/batiste/django-continuous-integration) project.

Comment: Thanks, Oliver. This is a good start for me.

Answer (score 4):

I like a couple of Pragmatic Programmers' books on this subject, [Ship it!](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0974514047) and [Release it!](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0978739213).  Together, they teach a lot of real-world, pragmatic stuff about such things as build systems and how to design well-deployable programs.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this in Java, you can check out Maven. There are a host of tutorials for it:

- [Maven in Five Minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)
- [The Maven Tutorial: A practical guide for Maven 2 users](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/The+Maven+2+tutorial)
- [Maven: The definitive Guide](http://www.sonatype.com/products/maven/documentation/book-defguide) (book)

All of this falls under the category of Software-Development Principles, Software-Design Philosophy, Software-Configuration Management, and Build and Release Management:

- [Best practices for build and release management](http://www.viewtier.com/support/articles/best_practices_for_software_build_management.htm)
- [High-level best practices in Software-Configuration Management](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/papers/bestpractices.html)
- [Software-Configuration Management Best Principles](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=422304)

It's a moderately-involved field. After years of programming, I'm still learning and understanding new things about build-management and software-configuration management.

Answer (score 1):

For Python projects you should use setuptools.  Setuptools has all the stuff to pack things up into .eggs, compile C modules, run unit tests, etc...  If you've ever done "python setup.py [build|install|test]" then you've used setuptools.

Comment: Where can I find resource about how to use setuptools?

Answer (score 0):

While this is certainly not a complete answer to your question, I would like to recommend very highly the learning of the tool 'make'.  I find myself using it on a VERY regular basis, for a wide variety of tasks, including (but by no means limited to) building, testing, and deploying software.